# Remove all video attachment, both files and post/postmeta from database?

Tags: functions, customization, user-roles, attachments

I am trying to make a function which deletes all the video files + the attachment post and attachments postmeta from the database. This should run when the user role is switched to "basic".
And if the post_mime_type begins with "video", as it can be either video/mp4 or video/quicktime etc...
I have come this far, but I cannot figure it out fully:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles )
{
    if ( 'basic' == $role ) {
        $args = array(
            'fields'          => 'ids',
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type'       => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type'  => array('video/x-ms-asf','video/x-ms-wmv','video/x-ms-wmx','video/x-ms-wm','video/avi','video/divx','video/x-flv','video/quicktime','video/mpeg','video/mp4','video/ogg','video/webm','video/x-matroska')
        );
        $all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
            foreach ( $all_ids->posts as $post ) {
                wp_delete_attachment( $post->ID, true );
            }
        }
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

This is not working, as I really don't know what I am missing!

Used my existing function as guideline which works well. This one changes a meta_value to empty.

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles )
{
    if ( 'basic' == $role ) {
            $args = array( 'fields'          => 'ids',
                           'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                           'post_type'       => 'slide',
                           'meta_key'        => 'background-video'
                           );
            $all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
                    $all_ids->the_post();
                    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'background-video', '' );
                }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: change `wp_delete_attachment( $attachmentid, $force_delete );` to `wp_delete_attachment( get_the_ID());`. If you want to bypass trash  `wp_delete_attachment( get_the_ID(), true);`

Comment: I tried this, but sadly nothing happens? I also tried the suggested answer underneath without anything happening!

Answer (score 0):

You call `wp_delete_attachment` passing `$attachmentid` which is undefined, so it can't work... Also the `$force_delete` variable isn't defined anywhere in your code.

Also there is no point in using normal loop in here - you don't use template tags in this action, so calling `the_post` is just a waste of resources...

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles )
{
    if ( 'basic' == $role ) {
        $args = array(
            'fields'          => 'ids',
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type'       => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type'  => 'video'
        );
        $all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $all_ids->have_posts() ) {
            foreach ( $all_ids->posts as $post ) {
                wp_delete_attachment( $post->ID );
                // wp_delete_attachment( $post->ID, true );  // <- use this, if you wan't to bypass trash
            }
        }
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Will this delete all attachment with post_mime_type starting with video regardless if it is called video/mp4 or video/quicktime?

Comment: It will delete attachments that are selected with the query you use in your question. If you want to delete all videos, regardless of it's type, it would be best to pass mime type argument as an array. And you can find list of all available (by default) mime types here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types

Comment: I just tried this code, including the array (check the first post, edited it with the function I have tested). But it does nothing, no files are deleted from the ftp, no attachment posts or postmeta are removed either.

Comment: And what is role „basic”? Are you sure there is such role and your code is running?

Comment: Yes, basic is a role I have created! I posted another function (check first post) which I am currently using that works very well. That is where I got the first parts from. So I know that part are correct. But I cannot make this one work?